# C++ Multiple libraries depending on one library

Tags: c++, cross-platform, libraries

I have written a library that provides to me basic debugging functionality, that can be stripped at compile time. I have been using this library in almost all my projects, however, I have come to a situation where I have created 3 libraries in a project I am working on that all depend on the same library. Because of this, in their own subdirs, they all build the code for this debugging lib independently, and this is not optimal. I am wondering how I would go about mitigating this problem, in a cross platform fashion.

project layout:

```
proj
  \__ src
  |
  \__ foo_lib
  |      \__ src
  |      \__ debug_lib
  |
  \__ bar_lib
         \__ src
         \__ debug_lib
```

If this were a git repository, which is is, I would have 2 sub-dependencies that have the debug lib as a sub-dependency. Because of this, in addition to compiling both, I would have to download both whenever cloning the repository.

My friend told me about installing a global library, but I could only figure out how to do this on my Linux machine, not Windows.

**EDIT: Addendum from comment**

I would like to have the ability to debug through the source of the project (ie. breakpoints and navigation through source) while developing with it, and would not like to pre-compile binaries to ship with my git repos.

Comment: I think `CMake` is an option for setting this up with proper dependency handling in a  cross platform manner, however I don't fully understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

1. Is this a static library?

Compile it only 4 times (x86,x64,debug,release) then just include the .lib in all your projects and use the .h file.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"debuglib.lib");
```

2. Is this a DLL ?  You can install it in the system (bad practise).
3. Can this be a header-only library? no need for binaries.

Comment: I would like to have the ability to debug through the source of the project (ie breakpoints and navigation through source) while developing with it, thus this does not answer the question. Also, this would require me to include a binary in my github projects, which I think is bad practice, and not crossplatform.

Comment: Including the debug version of the .lib and having the source code available allows you to debug the source of the library.

Comment: This is still not cross platform, and does not solve the problem of having to include 4 binaries inside every project that uses it. The idea of it being header only is a good idea, however, it does not solve the problem of having to download all the headers as a sub-dependency for every library or project that uses it

Comment: i think you just want to achieve the most great result with the least possible work. All that "problems" you refer to are daily issues for most programmers.  Sorry, I can't help more.

Comment: Do you have an answer for what to do for Linux and MacOS instead of trying to insult me? Do you think I should have 4 libraries for each OS? Are you saying I should distribute 12+ binaries in a git repo? or just sources and headers, then force the person using it to download the code separately, compile and copy around the binaries in a non automatable way...? Edit: He removed the insult

Comment: You never understood the meaning of 4 libraries. It's for x64 and x86 , in release and debug compilations, 4 for *one OS* only and without reistribution. You would only use them yourself. A github user can rebuild them from the source. You would need another 4 for all the Oses.

Comment: So...I did understand, and referenced exactly what you're trying to explain in my last comment:
> "or just sources and headers, then force the person using it to download the code separately, compile and copy around the binaries in a non automatable way.", my question still stands